# Improving performance of javascript intervals on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm using javascript loop (using `setInterval`) that runs through a list of search results, highlighting the search term by adding a css styled `<span>` around search hits as it goes.  I'm using `setInterval` like this to release control of the browser while it does this.

In Chrome and Firefox this works well - even with a setInterval parameter of 10-20ms; and the user has full control of the browser (i.e. scrolling, clicking links etc.) while the results are rapidly highlighted:

```js
mylooper = setInterval(function() {
    // my functionality is here
},15); // 15ms
```

Unfortunately, when using the dreaded IE8, the browser locks up and takes a *really* long time to add the `<span>`'s and style the search results.  It also takes a long time just to load the page in the first place - shortened a great deal when this script is removed.

So far I've tried:

- changing the interval values (I've read that IE8 doesn't detect intervals of sub 15ms);
- using `setTimeout` instead of setInterval;
- removing the interval to check that this is in fact what is causing the slow-down (it is!); and
- swearing about Internet Explorer a lot;

  ```js
  var highlightLoop;
  var index = 0;

  highlightLoop = setInterval(function () {

  var regex = RegExp(regexPhrase, "gi"); // regexPhase created elsewhere
  var searchResults = resultElements.eq(index).get(0); // run through resultElements which contain alll the nodes with search results in them.

    findAndReplaceDOMText( // a function that does the searching and inserting of styling
      regex,
      searchResults,
      function (fill, matchIndex) {
        called = true;
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.className = "result-highlight";
        span.innerHTML = fill;
        return span;
      }
    );
    if (index == resultElements.length || searchTermUpdated == true) { // stop interval loop when search term changes or we reach the end of results - variable set elsewhere.
      searchTermUpdated = false;
      clearInterval(highlightLoop); // stop the loop
    }
    index++
  }
  }, 50); // 50ms does not improve performance.
  ```

Any advice on workarounds for this kind of javascripting in IE would be massively appreciated.  Thanks all.

Comment: Why have you bound this to an interval? Why not just bind it to the `change` or `keyup` event of the the search input?

Comment: In order to try and release control to the browser - the overall `highlightloop = setInterval` is only called when the search field is updated/edited.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be able to improve the performance by tweaking `findAndReplaceDOMText`, and maybe its callback too. I suppose `findAndReplaceDOMText` appends the element returned by the callback to the DOM, from within a loop of all matches. If it's doing that inside a loop, try to move it outside the loop, and apply the all changes to the DOM at once. That should result in better performance, as repainting the page after each DOM update is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive approach instead:

- get a list of all elements to be acted upon into array X (one time cost)
- while the array X has length, keep repeating the next actions

  - shift the first element off the array
  - process the single element
  - start this process again with the new array X (now X<sub>n</sub> - 1 length) on a `setTimeout`

The code looks like this in general

```
function processArray(array) {
  var element = array.shift();
  processElement(element);
  if (array)
    setTimeout(function(){processArray(array);},15ms);
}
```

There might be something else to be done with this recursion, but it works fairly well in all browsers and never blocks, because you're only initiating the repeat when the last one has had time to finish.

Comment: Okay thanks for the suggestion - I'm having a go at implementing this now.  How is the function initialised though?  Does it just need to be kicked off on page load?

Comment: Yeah, once you build that one-time-cost array, you can initiate it whenever.